# Verifying smoothness of a specific 1-form

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm having trouble understanding the following:

[image: pic]

My initial thought was that the 1-form is "obviously" smooth, since the coefficient functions are smooth. But then why would the author say that the 1-form $r^2 d\phi$ and the function after that are smooth? Why does it matter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$d\phi =\dfrac{-y\,dx+x\,dy}{x^2+y^2}$ is smooth away from the $z$-axis, but $r^2\,d\phi$ is smooth everywhere.

Comment: So, essentially, this ensures that the part "$+r \sin{r} d\phi$" is smooth? I thought that you only needed to check that the coordinate functions were smooth?

Comment: Yeah, if you really had globally-defined coordinates, but $r$ is not everywhere smooth and $\phi$ is not globally defined!